# Aktau, Kazakhstan to Bukhara, Uzbekistan?

Tags: trains, uzbekistan, kazakhstan, aktau, bukhara

I'm currently in Aqtau/Aktau, Kazakhstan.  The trains look really tricky to get to Bukhara, and I'm wondering if there's a better way, as currently it looks like going back up the line to Beynou (no choice) at night, waiting until the early morning train from there to Nukus or Kungrad, and then down to Navoi, and then hoping there's a train, bus or taxi from there to Bukhara? The train line doesn't seem to go direct to Bukhara unless you go all the way to Samarkand/Tashkent and route back in?

Any better suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately, can't find any appropriate route for you. I have a feeling that you'll have to get to the Tashkent

Comment: Is hitchhiking a possibility? Works great in East Asia and Western Asia but I've never been to Central Asia...

Comment: http://dialssoft.com/blog/?p=25 - only in russian, and by car.

Comment: Hmm, thanks guys.  I've bought a ticket to Beynou, and then an hour later have a second one to Kungrad in Uzbekistan - it's the closest I can get booking from here.  I guess when I arrive I'll look at buses / trains / hitching from there :) Thanks for the suggestion re hitching, haven't done that in a while, might be fun.

Comment: [About hitchhiking](http://wulffmorgenthaler.com/img/strip/-WM_strip_DK_20110715.jpg)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out there's no direct easy way.  Best way is to get a ticket to Beynou, and change an hour later for the train to Kungrad.  From there local Uzbekistan transport will get one closer.

I ended up getting a shared taxi from Kungrad to Nukus (10,000 soms), then decided to go via Khiva.  Nukus to Khiva was 25000 soms in a shared taxi, and from there bus and taxi options are available to Bukhara.